# Facebook oauth rest api redirect uri issue with opencart

Tags: php, facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have to implement authorization with Google and Facebook on OpenCart website. I have no problems with Google rest api, but some with Facebook.
So, oauth rest api method is pretty simple.

```html
<?php
  $client_id = APP_ID; // Client ID
  $client_secret = APP_SECRET; // Client secret
  $redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/facebook-login/index.php'; // Redirect URIs

  $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth';
 
 $params = array(
     'client_id'     => $client_id,
     'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
     'response_type' => 'code',
     'scope'         => 'email'
 );

 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

     $params = array(
         'client_id'     => $client_id,
         'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
         'client_secret' => $client_secret,
         'code'          => $_GET['code']
     );
 
     $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';

     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     $result = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     $tokenInfo = json_decode($result, true);
     
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($tokenInfo);
     echo '</pre>';

     if (count($tokenInfo) > 0 && isset($tokenInfo['access_token'])) {
         $params = array('access_token' => $tokenInfo['access_token']);
         $params = array(
             'fields' => 'id,name,email', 
             'access_token' => $tokenInfo['access_token']
         );
 
         $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
 
         if (isset($userInfo['id'])) {
             echo '<pre>';
             print_r($userInfo);
             echo '</pre>';
         }
     }

 } else {
  
  $loginUrl = $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($loginUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
 }
```

And this code works fine until your redirect uri link does not contain OpenCart's "route" params or something like this!

So, if my $redirect_uri variable equals "https://example.com/facebook-login/" it's ok. But when I try to implement this script on any of openCart's page (for e.g. "https://example.com/index.php?route=account/login/facebook") it fails because Facebook oauth api throws exception: "**Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request**".

I tried to encode slashes but to no avail. So why Google rest api works fine with this redirect uri but Facebook doesn't? Why does it have very strict rules?

Could somebody help me please to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `urldecode` on the query string you are building when passing it to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Comment: Thank you very much! Its working now) I just cpoied this sample from one tutorial and didn't pay attention to this moment. But there is one nuance -
 all slashes (only slashes!) in "route" param must be encoded anyway. So my redirect uri link should be looking exactly like this 'https://example.com/index.php?route=account%2FFlogin%2Ffacebook'. Strange.